# Trigger to delete after insert

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have two tables, new table and registered table, what I want is that what is new will be registered when an update is made to a boolean (Accepted = 1 send it to registered) and after the information has been inserted back to registered delete that same one again, try to make a trigger that would do that but although it saves me well when doing this operation the trigger does not advance and does not do the operations

```
BEGIN
CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_1` AFTER UPDATE ON `new` 
FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO registered (Num_Registered, Name_Registered, Type_Id, Semes_Registered, Fac_Registered, Pass) SELECT Mat_New, Name_New, Id_New, Semes_New, Fac_New, Pass_New FROM new WHERE Accepted=1;

DELETE FROM new WHERE Accepted=1 OR Accepted=0;//Here taking into account that 0 is rejected and deleted, and 1 is accepted and sent to registered
END;
```

In the same way I tried to make 2 triggers (one that made the insertion of one table to another and then another trigger that after the insertion deletes said in the table first) but they only collide with each other * error 1442 -cant update table new in stored function / trigger because it is already in use by statement which invoked this stored function / trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_1` BEFORE UPDATE ON `new`
FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO registered (Num_Registered, Name_Registered, Type_Id, Semes_Registered, Fac_Registered, Pass) SELECT Mat_New, Name_New, Id_New, Semes_New, Fac_New, Pass_New FROM new WHERE Accepted=1;


CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_2` AFTER UPDATE ON `new`
 FOR EACH ROW DELETE FROM new WHERE Accepted=1 OR Accepted=0;//Here taking into account that 0 is rejected and deleted, and 1 is accepted and sent to registered
```

Comment: Surely it would just be easier to have a `status` Column on registered table (and call that table user or something) then users can be in status new or registered ...

Comment: Is that my database is connected in an application, so those who register will still go through an acceptance process to the request (that's why the accepted one) I want to move from my new table to my registered table if in case they accept the request Accepted = 1 or deleted from the database if Accepted = 0
So when you log in you can only compare the password and username without using the status, so I try to find a way to do it

Comment: Can you talk a bit more about the system in terms of data flows. Tell us what is inserted into each table and when, and what you want inserted or updated in some other table as a result. I don't care so much about the triggers that didn't work, though they're helpful to know your column names. Ask your question like "when a user registers their details are put in the registered table with status = 0, and I want to trigger at that point to move them into the `new` (terrible name for a table btw) table with status 1 and delete them from registered. Later, when the x column in new is updated I ..

Comment: @Near343 . . . Basically, you want to turn an `update` into a `delete`.  I don't know if this is possible in MySQL.

Comment: First a user submits his registration request, then the administrator UPDATES his row in the accepted section, where he will say Accepted = 0 if his information is not correct or Accepted = 1 if his information is correct. Then either Accepted = 1 or Accepted = 0 I deleted it from the "new" table, of course, if Accepted = 1, first send said information from the "new" table to the registered table, and then delete it later

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the insert into the `registrations` table is simple.  And I can understand reasons why  you would want this.  For instance, you might have additional data for the "accepted" folks.  You might want foreign key relationships only to "accepted".

The challenge is that you want the `update` to turn into a `delete`.   I don't think that is possible in a trigger in MySQL.  But a simple alternative is to just use a view:

```
create view v_new as
    select n.*
    from new n
    where n.accepted <> 1;
```

This also has the advantage that you have a record of everyone who was ever new, even though they would not be visible to the users who use the view.

Comment: I think that is a good idea,  but I really want to delete the information of table new, doesn't exist another way to do it? To be honest, I don't care if I use triggers or procedures or views, I just want to delete from the new table